# "Attempting to use an incompatible return type" with Interface Inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance, interface

I'm running into a problem with incompatible return types using inheritance.

```
public interface A { }
public interface B extends A { }

public interface C {
    Map<String, A> getMapping();
}

public interface D extends C {
    Map<String, B> getMapping();
}
```

Is there a way to make this work?

Right now the compiler tells me I'm 'Attempting to use an incompatible return type' on interface D.

Comment: @alfasin correct, questions updated - sorry!

Comment: That's a big change to your question. @user3707125: has your solution then.

Comment: Sounds like an answer here guys...

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I suggest you use

```
interface C {
    Map<String, ? extends A> getMapping();
}
```

This says *"A map that maps `String` to `A` or a subtype of `A`"*. This is compatible with `Map<String, B>`.

Comment: Yes! This was driving me crazy. I had an interface method declared to return a `Set<MyObjectInterface>` and an implementing class set to return `Set<MyObject>`. This was resulting in the error in the question. Changing the interface declaration to `Set<? extends MyObjectInterface>` fixed my problem. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks very much.  This was driving me crazy and it is such a simple fix.

Comment: When will Java implement real Polymorphism.... instead of getting programers to use workarounds?

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on nested generic containers. I tried something similar for a method that returns `Collection<Collection<? extends MyInterface>>` and I still get the error. I did try it with a standalone Collection and it works.

Answer (score 1):

Make the following changes:

```
interface C<E extends A> {
    Map<String, E> getMapping();
}

interface D extends C<B> {
    Map<String, B> getMapping();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As an addition to the accepted answer, I ran into a problem when using nested typed data structures. For example, if you create an abstract method in your interface such as:

```
Collection<Collection<? extends InterfaceB>> doSomething();
```

Then the accepted answer would imply that this is should work:

```
@Override
Collection<Collection<InterfaceBImplementation>> doSomething() {

... doing stuff...

return stuff;
}
```

However, you will receive the same clashing/incompatible return type error. Instead, you have to also wild card the inner collection in the abstract method:

```
Collection<? Collection<? extends InterfaceB>> doSomething();
```

I don't understand why this works, or why it's set up that way but there ya go.